# What ComponentQuery should I use for this example in this.control()?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I have:[image]

1.) What should I type in this.control() for getting the reference to the grid panel?

My plan is, when user double clicks one row, new tab is created. I already have code for creating new tabs but I just need to get reference to the grid panel.

Something like this:

```
'viewport > westpanel > accordion > gridpanel': {
   doubleclick: function...
}
```

2.) Let's say that I gave an ID to the grid panel. How can I get reference in this.control using .get method?

3.) How can I be sure that I've got the right reference? Can I console.log() - it or something like that?

I would know how to do this without MVC but here I need help. :)

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy once you understand how to use it. First you should read the API about the [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) cause that is what is used within the control.

1. this depends on your components. You so can go by the xtype `'panel > grid': {itemdblclick:this.yourCallback}`
2. the recommend way if you can't define a really unique path by xtypes `'#myID': {itemdblclick:this.yourCallback}` using defined refs within the control is not possible in the currently release, as far as I know.
3. Use Id's instead of just xtypes `'#myID > grid': {itemdblclick:this.yourCallback}` or define additional params `'#myID > grid[customProp=identString]': {itemdblclick:this.yourCallback}`

Comment: it is recommended to NOT use ids in extjs

Comment: You could say the same for any other HTML site... It is only not recommend cause a auto-Id system is saver than programmers who write them. But if you use a Id system that is based on a strong convention there is no problem doing so. ExtJS create a Id for each component if there is no Id already setted by the user.